# Does this proof of the existence of an injective function need the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: functions, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $f$ be an injective function from $C$ to a partition $P$ of $B$, i.e. $f:C\rightarrow P$. Let $g$ be an injective function from $B$ to a partition $Q$ of $A$, i.e. $g:B\rightarrow Q$. How do I show that there is an injective function $h$ from $C$ to $Q$, i.e. $h:C\rightarrow Q$?

If the Axiom of Choice is assumed, then there is an injective function $f’$ from $P$ to $B$. Then, we can prove that $h$ exists because functions $f,f’,g$ can be composed together. How do I prove this without the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: What makes you think you can prove it without using AC?

Comment: I’m just curious. Given an arbitrary $x\in C$, we can define $h(x)=\bigcup_{y\in f(x)} g(y)$. Seems like AC isn’t needed?

Comment: So see if you can work that up into a proof.

Comment: I’ve tried that. It always needs AC. But I’m not sure if I’m correct. That’s why I’m turning to the experts here.

Comment: So show us your proof attempts, please.

Comment: Let $I$ be the index set of $B$. Let $f’_i$ be the choice function on $P$ that picks out $\omega_i \in B$ such that $i\in I$. We can then define $f’’_i$ to be the composition of $f$ and $f’_i$.  $h_i$ can be defined as the composition of $f’’_i$ and $g$. $h = \bigcup_{i\in I} h_i$. With AC, $f’_i$ exists. But without it, it cannot be proven to exist and therefore $h$ cannot be proven to exist.

Comment: Your claim in terms of cardinalities is as follows: if $|C|\le|P|\le^* |B|\le |Q|$ then $|C|\le |Q|$. (Here $|X|\le^*|Y|$ means there is a surjection from $Y$ to $X$, or equivalently, there is a partition of $Y$ of size $|X|$.) The special case of your claim, namely the case $C=P$ and $B=Q$, is known as the *Partition Principle*.

Comment: The Partition Principle is independent of $\mathsf{ZF}$ (as far as I know) so you must use $\mathsf{AC}$ to prove your claim. Whether the partition principle is equivalent to $\mathsf{AC}$ is an open problem.